# Eliminate ID if Col2 = (1,2,3)

Tags: teradata

I am using teradata sql, and I have the following input

[image: table1]

If *col2* has (1,2,3) values then delete the Id from table, so my desired table is:

[image: Table2]

I tried all possible ways, but cannot get to eliminate the IDs? Any help or suggestion will help. thanks

Comment: hi, can you please share your desired output.

Comment: similar to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84297/select-rows-with-same-id-but-null-and-some-other-value-in-another-column-for-tha

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to delete those IDs you better use @MudassirHasan's solution, but if you want to select the other IDs you can utilize *Conditional Aggregation* in a Group Max:

```
select *
from mytable
qualify
   max(case when col2 (1,2,3) then 1 else 0 end) -- will return zero when those values don't exist
   over (partition by id) = 0                    -- for an ID
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it?

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE Id IN ( SELECT Id FROM yourTable WHERE col2 IN (1,2,3) )
```

Comment: Please provide some explanations.